# Is there a way like man, info, perldoc etc to get help info about C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have some experience with Bash, Perl and R. I find it is very convenient to get help info with these three programming languages. However, when I start with C++, I fail to find such a help system. Did I miss something? Or, there is no such system at all?

Another problem puzzling me is C++ libraries. How to start to learn a new library? Is there a convenient way to get all the member functions for a new class? Or, do we have to read the header files to get the methods for the class?

Thanks!

Comment: For learning a new library, read its documentation.

Comment: Reading a book is the best way to learn C++. It can't be learnt by trial and error.

Comment: Functions in the C and C++ standard libraries as well as many third-party libraries should be listed in `man`.  None of the systems you mentioned is any help for a third-party library in any of those languages, if the third-party didn't provide documentation in the corresponding format.

Comment: @Matt: I am reading C++ Primer. But I want to know if there is a way to immediately get help info about a C++ function etc.

Comment: Also, try cppreference.com, though the question linked by remyabel should answer your immediate needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have experience with bash, then you must be familiar with `unix` or `linux` systems, you can use man command like `man 2 fwrite` to find the standard c library manual for `fwrite` function.

However, for c-plus-plus, the manual is not inside the man directory by default (so far as I know).
You can download c-plus-plus manual from 'http://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html' to use `manual for c++ standard library`. Or try to use `dash` on Mac computer or `Velocity` on Windows platform instead. Besides, reading the manual from 'http://en.cppreference.com/w/' is my favorite way.

Comment: Thanks for the useful discussion. I've found what I want via these two URLs: (1) I work on CentOS, this URL answered my question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12688/man-pages-for-standard-c-and-c-libraries-on-fedora-14 (2) aitjcize developed a package -- cppman. I think this is of great help. https://github.com/aitjcize/cppman